# rails xml to active record object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, serialization, activerecord

I've been googling for a while to try and convert and incoming XML request into an active record object. I've tried using the ActiveRecordObject.new.from_xml method but it doesn't seem to handle relationships.

For example, say I have the following xml:

```
<blog>
  <title></title>
  <blog-pages>
    <blog-page>
      <page-number></page-number>
      <content></content>
    </blog-page>
  </blog-pages>
</blog>
```

And I have the following model objects:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :blog_pages

end

class BlogPage < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :blog

end
```

Is there a way to convert the xml into a blog object WITH relationships? Or do I need to manually parse the XML?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I banged my head up against this for a while.  It seems there's not much out there to map XML to ActiveRecord objects without doing it manually.  While my needs were similar to yours I needed also needed to not just do one object with relationships, I needed to do many.  I looked in a lot of places and couldn't find anything.  I decided to solve it myself but realised that it wasn't going to be a one liner so wrote a gem that extended ActiveRecord.  I based on the work by Wayne Robinson:

http://www.wayne-robinson.com/journal/2006/5/1/ruby-on-rails-activerecordbuild_from_xml-function.html

After a couple of months in my non existant spare time I finished my gem and you can check out at RubyGems: https://rubygems.org/gems/xml_active

Hope this helps :)
Cheers,

Michael

UPDATE

xml_active has now been officially retired and development is now focused on data_active (see https://github.com/michael-harrison/data_active) which has the functionality of xml_active but in future releases I will be working to support other formats

Comment: Just a quick one.. What did you do to expand the work by wayne?

Comment: @daveatflow, xml_active (now data_active) was based on Wayne's work to introspect the model dependencies then create objects memory.  The gem takes the next step of committing the new objects to the database. It also provides support for has_one associations where Wayne's work only really handles has_many associations.  In short his work inspired me to build the gem to not only scratch my own itch but hopefully help others.  I though it only fitting that I give him the kudos ;)

Answer (score 0):

Look here:
http://www.wayne-robinson.com/journal/2006/5/1/ruby-on-rails-activerecordbuild_from_xml-function.html